# Which method will be called?

Tags: java

For example we have a class `Test` which overloads 2 methods (just call it **ambiguousMethod**) with **arguments :  1 method has short, another has int, but different types**. In this situation consider that type is **short** and **int**. And then I call this method from main like this:

```
double d = new Test.ambiguousMethod(3);
```

So which method will be called? With INT or with SHORT return types?

Thanks

it's my code:

```
Method a = new Method();
double d= a.print(3);


class Method {

    public int print(int a)
    {
        return a;

    }

    public short print(short b){
        return b;
    }

}
```

Comment: Return type doesn't take part in the uniqueness of a method: you're program won't compile.

Comment: I would say first try to see if your program compiles at all!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Neither will be called, because that program won't compile.  Two same-named methods with no arguments have the same method signature regardless of return type, and that is a compiler error in Java.

Note: This answer above was given when the question stated that two same-named methods had no arguments and different return types.  It has since changed to something different.

For the "updated" question:

You pass an `int` literal `3`, so the `int` method will be called.  To call the `short` method, cast the `3` to a `short`:

```
ambiguousMethod((short) 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in a literal `3`, then the method with an `int` argument will be called because `3` is implicitly typed as an `int` when no other expected type is indicated (unlike in the case of `short s = 3`).

Answer (score 0):

The default type for integer literals is int, so that version should be called.  If you want to call the other version with a literal, cast it.

Answer (score 0):

The method with `int` argument will be called, as numeric literal values have default type of `int` in Java.

If you *explicitly cast* it to `short` then it will call method with `short` arguments.

```
ambiguousMethod((short)3); //will call method with short args.
```